# Making a regression line through a bar char using pandas or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, trendline

I am new to Pandas and Seaborn and trying to learn. I am trying to add a trend line and a bar plot on the same graph. I have some data that looks like

```
Year     Sample Size
 2000      500
 2001      3000
 2003      10000
 2004      20000
 2004      23000
```

I am new to pandas and seaborn and I am attempting to draw a line through the bar plot showing a decreasing or an increasing trend but struggling to do it on the same graph. Till now, I have a bar plot. Below you can find the code.

sampleSizes['Sample Size'] -> is the column I am plotting. It has about 12 values for 12 years.

```
plt.figure()
ax = sampleSizes['Sample Size'].plot(kind='bar', title="Trend of Sample Sizes", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, color = 'grey', fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

I am struggling to add a trend line to this. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

UPDATE

```
FinancialYear  Sample Size
   2001         2338
   2002         3171
   2003         2597
   2004         2740
   2005         3447
   2006         3098
   2007         2610
   2008         2819
   2009         2057
   2010         2174
   2011         2709

enter code here
```

Comment: Is a bar plot the right type of representation for this? Or would a line plot be more appropriate? There's also [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html), but it sounds like your data is not linear at all.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy yes, I agree line plot would be better but I am trying to have the bar graphs and a line showing the trend of the data on the same graph. I hope it makes it clear what I'm trying to achieve. I have edited the data above a bit. I just randomly got these numbers. The numbers are not necessarily representative of my data. However, the variables are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** using updated data set

```
In [250]: lr = Ridge()

In [251]: lr.fit(df[['FinancialYear']], df['Sample Size'])
Out[251]:
Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

In [252]: plt.bar(df['FinancialYear'], df['Sample Size'])
Out[252]: <Container object of 11 artists>

In [253]: plt.plot(df['FinancialYear'], lr.coef_*df['FinancialYear']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
Out[253]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x171def60>]
```

Result:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [184]: from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

In [185]: lr = Ridge()

In [186]: lr.fit(df[['Year']], df['Sample Size'])
Out[186]:
Ridge(alpha=1.0, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=None,
   normalize=False, random_state=None, solver='auto', tol=0.001)

In [187]: plt.bar(df['Year'], df['Sample Size'])
Out[187]: <Container object of 5 artists>

In [188]: plt.plot(df['Year'], lr.coef_*df['Year']+lr.intercept_, color='orange')
Out[188]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x17062898>]
```

Result:

[image]

---

Try to use matplotlib methods for that:

```
plt.bar(df['Year'], df['Sample Size'])
plt.plot(df['Year'], df['Sample Size'], '-o', color='orange')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am able to do that. I am trying to make a smoother line like a regression line just showing the general trend. Like a straight upward line (like in a linear regression) instead of it being joined.

Comment: @paddy, please check updated answer - is that what you want?

Comment: OMG YES. Thank you so much. Been trying so hard for the past hour

Comment: @MaxU Its weird. So your code works when I have all 12 values. When I remove one because of it being an outlier, it seems to crash. Any reason you could see why that would happen?

Comment: @paddy, can you provide a reproducible data set?

Comment: @MaxU Updated my description. When I remove the value from year 2000, it crashes

Comment: @paddy, linear function doesn't fit well to this data. I'd think of using higher polynomial here...

Comment: @MaxU so what did you use here? It seems you've pasted the same code by mistake