# Basic trendline in pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, trendline

I created plots from the data frame with pandas.

Example;

```
plt_promoted_followers = promoted_followers.plot(x="date", y="followers", color='red')
plt_promoted_followers.set(xlabel="Date", ylabel="Followers in billion")
```

I saw last of different methods, which is the easiest way to draw a trendline in this plot.

Sorry if it is so easy question :)

Comment: What did you try already? You should search for `numpy` or `scipy` fitting routines, these are straight forward for trendlines

Comment: for example ;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842293/making-a-regression-line-through-a-bar-char-using-pandas-or-seaborn